# Android ListView row not visible

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am trying to make a ListView row that has an icon to the left, followed by two stacked rows to the right.  However, for some reason the bottom row on the right is not showing up.  My question to the StackOverflow experts is:  what is incorrect in my XML to make the bottom row not show up?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ap" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bssid"
            android:layout_width="140dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ssid"
            android:layout_width="190dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bssid"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enc"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ssid"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/power"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/enc"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

     </RelativeLayout>
     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_height="20dip"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mgmt"
            android:layout_width="55dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="55dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mgmt"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/manuf"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/data"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastseen"
            android:layout_width="140dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/manuf"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:textColor="@color/foreground" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, if you have a better idea or way to do this, I am certainly open to it.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `2nd LinearLayout` (`4th view`) should have `40dip` as its height.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but that still didn't fix it.  The bottom row is still not visible.

Comment: Your linearlayout should have a orientation. sometimes missing this will messup the layouts.

Comment: That's it. By default, `LinearLayout` orientation is `horizontal`, you should set `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invisible listview item row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907172/invisible-listview-item-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aprian and @prijupaul figured this one out.  By default, LinearLayout is horizontal, and I needed it to be set to vertical.  So, I modified by LinearLayout to include:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

... and it works correctly.  Thank both of you for your help.