# How to add Search functionality on list view items in listview are from BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have to add search functionality on Edittext items in listview are coming from baseadapter
I am using this code but  .getFilter().filter(s.toString()); is not coming

My Code is:

```
approvedfriendList.setAdapter(new ApprovedList());

            //*********Search Functionality in Approved Friend List************************
            serch_item.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //  approvedfriendList.getFilterTouchesWhenObscured().f
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    approvedfriendList is ArrayList
```

I am not getting how to use here .getFilter().filter(s.toString()); with ApprovedList()(Base Adapter Class )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext/15367403#15367403. check the link for custom search. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ search in listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should enable your list view for filtering by adding this line of code :

```
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

then simply add a text watcher in your text view :

```
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              adapter.getFilter().filter( s.toString());
              list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable prefix) { 
        }       

    });
```

Comment: I get an error and my app FC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a search of contacts in my app. Followimg is a part of the code:

```
searchContacts.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                temp.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < emailIds.size(); i++) {
                    if (emailIds.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toString())) {
                        temp.add(emailIds.get(i));
                    }
                }
                Collections.sort(temp);
                contacts.notifyDataSetChanged();

                for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                    if (sqlHandler.isChecked(temp.get(i))) {
                        lvContacts.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    } else {
                        lvContacts.setItemChecked(i, false);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```