# How to Implement ListView while fetching data from server

Tags: android, android-listview

I have written a program to **fetch data from Server** and to show in Android Activity using `TextView`(s), and now i **want to show those data into List using `ListView`**, but i don't know *how i need to implement `ListView` in my code to show data in a List*.

I am *fetching two fields* from every row, namely : **TotalAmount** and **ItemDetails**.

**Note:** I have written XML File also for `ListView` namely- **listrow_orders**

*Please i don't require any other tutorial link, brief me according to my code, it would be better for best understanding.*

**OrdersActivity.java:**

```
 public class OrdersActivity extends Activity 
{ 
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "OrdersActivity";

    TextView txtDetail,txtAmount ;
    String MemberID,resultServer,strTotal,strDetails,strOrderID;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }           

            txtAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalAmount);
            txtDetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtItemDetails);

            String url = "http://172.16.0.4/res/order_fetch.php";
            Intent intent= getIntent();
            MemberID = intent.getStringExtra("MemberID");
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sMemberID", MemberID));
            resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);

            strTotal = "";
            strDetails = "";

            JSONObject c;
            try {
            c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
            strTotal = c.getString("TotalAmount");  
            Log.d("Total Amount::", " "+strTotal);
            strDetails = c.getString("ItemDetails");
            Log.d("Item Details::", " "+strDetails);

            if(!strDetails.equals(""))
            {                   
                txtAmount.setText(strTotal);
                txtDetail.setText(strDetails);              
            }
            else
            {               
                txtDetail.setText("-");
                txtDetail.setText("-");
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }       

    }
```

**activity_orders.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/list_orders" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:divider="#b5b5b5" 
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**listrow_orders.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="Item Details Here" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Total Amount:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#a60704" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
    android:text="Ordered Items:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#a60704" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use a custom listview with a custom adapter. example shows image and text. instead of image you can show text http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Google Android custom BaseAdapter, that's your solution.

Comment: @Raghunandan if possible so please show me that few lines of code require to use in my program to implement ListView, big tutorial will not help me

Comment: @ChulbulPandey you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext/15367403#15367403. if it helps

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your post-request (since such stuff should not run in the gui thread, it will block it). For your results you best create a new class. For each result you create an instance of this class and put them in an `ArrayList`.

Secondly check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).
Use an `ArrayAdapter` -  there is no need for a custom adapter.