# Android: restart search thread

Tags: java, android, search, background-thread

I have a simple `EditText` with a `TextChangedListener` and a `ListView`.

The `onTextChanged` method will call the following `restartSearch` method, so the current search thread should be restarted while typing into the `EditText`.

The `search` method just adds matching items to the `ListView`.

When the `searchThread` is still alive, I want to cancel and restart the search so the UI doesn't freeze while typing and it doesn't take so long.

```
Thread searchThread;

private void restartSearch(CharSequence cs){
    query = cs;
    if(searchThread != null && searchThread.isAlive()){
        searchThread.interrupt();
    }
    searchThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(!lastSearch.equals(query))
                search(query);
        }
    });
    searchThread.start();
}
```

The method from where I call it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText etSearch = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch));

    //...

    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            restartSearch(s);
        }

        //...
    });
}
```

and another (from where I also update the UI):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what==1){
            //...
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            restartSearch(lastSearch);
        }
        else if(msg.what==2)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

the message `msg` is sent from the `search` method to update the UI:

```
private void search(CharSequence s){
        searchResults.clear();
    if(!s.toString().equals("")){
        for(int i=0; i<vocsCount; i++){
            try{
                getResult(i, 0, 2,s);
                getResult(i, 1, 1,s);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
        Collections.sort(searchResults);
    }
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = 2;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    lastSearch = s;
}
```

So as it creates a new `Runnable` every time, it seems as if they all run parallel, because all search-items are added multiple times to the ListView.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: can you post the search method?

Comment: you don't need a thread. post your search(query)

Comment: @Raghunandan I edited my question, I need an extra thread so I can cancel it while the user's typing.

Comment: i din't understand you comment. what do you mean by cancel.

Comment: @Raghunandan For example, when the user types "ab", the method `onTextChanged` will call the `restartSearch` method but the EditText text yet only is "a". To avoid searching for "a", I made a background thread which will be canceled to directly search for "ab", so the current background thread will be killed and recreated.

Comment: you don't need a thread at all. rethink your design. all you need a custom filter to search and update listview

Comment: @xoxox check this sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext/15367403#15367403. i don't use threads

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need to create a thread here. Because GUI is listening on a different thread and when it gives a callback on 'onTextChanged' that happens in a different thread. If these were not two different threads then you would have not been able to keep the GUI responsive while doing the search.

Comment: When I don't do the search in a background thread, the UI won't respond while typing.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Thread.interrupt()` but are you querying the value of `Thread.interrupted()` in your implementation of the thread?

You should check `Thread.interrupted()` before returning the result from your thread after you've done your search -or even better while you're doing your search if possible-