# Filter on CustomArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm new in Android, I followed some tutorials about adding search function on ListView, but in my case it's not working. Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code.

Here is my code:

**Activity.java**

```
public class SendMoney extends Activity {
    private ListView lvContacts;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private ContactListAdapter mAdapter;
    private String[] stockArr, stockArr1, stockArr2;
    private Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_money);

        initObjects();

        ArrayList<String> phoneContactList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> ContactImage = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> PhoneNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String img = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
              // This inner cursor is for contacts that have multiple numbers.
              Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
              while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                String pnumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                ContactImage.add(img);
                phoneContactList.add(name);
                PhoneNumber.add(pnumber);

                Log.i("Contact List", pnumber);
              }
              pCur.close();
            }
          }

          Collections.sort(phoneContactList);
          int cnt = phoneContactList.size(); // Count of contacts

          // Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] START

          // Contacts Name
          stockArr = new String[phoneContactList.size()];
          stockArr = phoneContactList.toArray(stockArr);

          // Contacts Photo
          stockArr1 = new String[ContactImage.size()];
          stockArr1 = ContactImage.toArray(stockArr1);

          // Contacts Number
          stockArr2 = new String[PhoneNumber.size()];
          stockArr2 = PhoneNumber.toArray(stockArr2);

          // Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] END

          mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.banks_listview_layout, stockArr, stockArr1);
          lvContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }
        cur.close();

        lvContacts.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lvContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {             
                i = new Intent(SendMoney.this, SendMoneyForm.class);
                i.putExtra("contact_name", stockArr[position]);
                i.putExtra("contact_image", stockArr1[position]);
                i.putExtra("contact_number", stockArr2[position]);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        //***************** SEARCH START ***********************

        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });

        //***************** SEARCH END ***********************
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.send_money, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void initObjects(){
        lvContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
        etSearch   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
    }
```

**my Custom Array Adapter**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String[] mStrings;
    private String[] mIcons;
    private int mViewResourceId;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context ctx, int resource,
            String[] option, String[] icons) {
        super(ctx, resource, option);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mStrings = option;
        mIcons   = icons;    
        mViewResourceId = resource;

    }

     @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mStrings.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mStrings[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivBankIcon);
            if(mIcons[position]==null) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_picture);
            } else {
                iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mIcons[position]));
                Log.d("LALA", mIcons[position]);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBankName);
            tv.setText(mStrings[position]);

            return convertView;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to elaborate on exactly what it is your piece of code should do and what exactly is not working. Makes it easier for people to provide an answer.

Comment: Check the code below of SEARCH START comment.. That code is my on search(filtering from ListView)

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in Custom Adapter . You are missing this method

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "**** PUBLISHING RESULTS for: " + constraint);
                myData = (List<MyDataType>) results.values;
                MyCustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "**** PERFORM FILTERING for: " + constraint);
                List<MyDataType> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: is this another method `getFilteredResults(constraint);`?

Comment: yep its another method where you filter what user type according to your need and generate a new array of data which will be displayed.

Comment: I can't understand how to implement this to my Adapter :(

Comment: you can follow this tutorial -- http://androidcocktail.blogspot.com/2012/04/search-custom-listview-in-android.html

its easy for you as u are new and also the tutorial u r following is not completed.

Comment: This tutorial works for me.. Thanks! Sorry for the late reply and voting up for your answer

Comment: I have one question.. In tutorial it if you search by last name it result nothing. But if you search by First name it works?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override `getFilter` method` and create your logic for filtering the data.

`public Filter getFilter()`

**Returns** a filter that can be used to constrain data with a filtering pattern.

This method is usually implemented by Adapter classes.

```
 EditText search= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
 search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                     adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

     }

     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
         int after) {

       }

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       }
      });
```

In your adapter

```
  @Override
  public Filter getFilter() {
  return new Filter() {
     @Override
     protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
         if (results != null && results.count >= 0) {
             //if results of search is not null set the searched results data
         } else {
            // set original values
         }

         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
     }
```

Then

```
    @Override
     protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
         if(condition)
            {

             ArrayList<MyDataType> foundItems = new ArrayList<MyDataType>();   
             // add items to foundItems if condition matches

             result.count = foundItems.size();//search results found return count
             result.values = foundItems;// return values
         }
         else
         {
             result.count=-1;// no search results found
         }


         return result;
     }
 };
```

}

Example:

[Search in ListView with EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext/15367403#15367403)