# How to add Search Edit text and List view?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-adapter, searchview

I am having a list view and an `EditText`. When i write on `EditText` i want to display my list view Starting with those alphabets. I am adding a custom adapter to My list view.

i have problem with `getFilter()` in `Edittext.addTextChangedListener`

My XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".menuucare.birthday.BirthdayActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_birthday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_birthday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="10dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center|left">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/back_birthday"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/back"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/search_birth"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:hint="Search here..."
                            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout9"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

BirthdayActivity.java

```
    public class BirthdayActivity extends ListActivity {

    private final DateFormatSymbols dateSymbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
    private Database db;
    private Button back_birthday;
    private ListView birthday;
    private TextView teks;
    private EditText search_birth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday);
        getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        this.db = new Database(getContentResolver());
        // debug code
        // Debug.logDatabase(this);

        // start BirthdayBroadcastReceiver if it is activated
        Preferences prefs = Preferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        if (prefs.getActivateService()) {
            BirthdayBroadcastReceiver.restart(getApplicationContext());
        }

        search_birth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_birth);

        back_birthday = findViewById(R.id.back_birthday);
        back_birthday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BirthdayActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateView();
    }

    private void updateView() {

        // create new list adapter
        final ListView ls = getListView();
        final MultiListAdapter listAdapter = new MultiListAdapter();
        final List<ListAdapter> adapterList = listAdapter.getListAdapters();
        ls.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent));
        ls.setDividerHeight(20);

        ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                List<Intent> targetShareIntents=new ArrayList<Intent>();
                Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
                if(!resInfos.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Have package");
                    for (ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
                        String packageName = resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                        Log.i("Package Name", packageName);
                        if (packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") || packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana") ||
                                packageName.contains("com.whatsapp") || packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.plus") ||
                                packageName.contains("com.google.android.gm")|| packageName.contains("com.yahoo.mobile") ||
                                packageName.contains("com.android.mms")|| packageName.contains("com.linkedin.android")||
                                packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.messaging")|| packageName.contains("jp.naver.line.android")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setType("text/plain");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Have the most happy and unforgettable birthday.\n\n - MemoMoo Apps -");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Birthday Card");
                            intent.setPackage(packageName);
                            targetShareIntents.add(intent);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!targetShareIntents.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Have Intent");
                        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetShareIntents.remove(0), "Choose app to share");
                        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
                        startActivity(chooserIntent);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Do not Have Intent");
                        // showDialaog(this);
                    }
                }

             /*   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Have the most happy and unforgettable birthday.\n\n - UCare Apps -");
                sendIntent.setType("text/");
                startActivity(sendIntent);*/
                }
        });

        // load birthday and contact information
        List<Contact> contacts = this.db.getAllContacts();
        List<BirthContact> birthContacts = BirthContactHelper.createBirthContactList(contacts);

        // group all contacts by known and unknown birthday
        SortedSet<BirthContact> knownBirthdays = new TreeSet(new BirthContactBirthdayComparator());

        for (BirthContact birthContact : birthContacts) {
            DateOfBirth dateOfBirth = birthContact.getDateOfBirth();

            if (dateOfBirth != null) {
                knownBirthdays.add(birthContact);
            }
        }

        Integer currentMonth = null;
        BirthdayContactAdapter currentBirthdayContactAdapter = null;
        String[] monthStrs = this.dateSymbols.getMonths();
        for (BirthContact birthContact : knownBirthdays) {
            int month = birthContact.getDateOfBirth().getDate().get(Calendar.MONTH);


                if (currentMonth == null || currentMonth != month) {
                    currentMonth = month;

                    currentBirthdayContactAdapter = new BirthdayContactAdapter(this);
                    adapterList.add(new CategoryAdapter(this, monthStrs[currentMonth]));
                    adapterList.add(currentBirthdayContactAdapter);

                }

                currentBirthdayContactAdapter.add(birthContact);

        }
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        search_birth.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void onBackPressed () {
        BirthdayActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

}
```

BirthdayContactAdapter.java

```
    public class BirthdayContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BirthContact> implements Filterable {
    private Typeface birthdaytextstyle;
    private TextView BirthdayTextStyle;
    private final Calendar today;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Resources res;
    private CardView card;
    private ArrayList<ListAdapter> data;

    public BirthdayContactAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.listviewbirthday);
        this.today = CalendarUtils.todaysCalendar();
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.res = context.getResources();
    }

    public BirthdayContactAdapter(Context context, Collection<BirthContact> birthContacts) {
        this(context);
        for (BirthContact birthContact : birthContacts) {
            add(birthContact);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        // create view if needed
        if (view == null) {
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewbirthday, null);
        }

        birthdaytextstyle = TextSettingActivity.typefacestyle;
        if(birthdaytextstyle != null){
            BirthdayTextStyle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            BirthdayTextStyle.setTypeface(birthdaytextstyle);}

        // set name
        BirthContact birthContact = getItem(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        String username = birthContact.getContact().getName();
        String Name = username + "'s Birthday is near, lets celebrate this wonderful moment!";
        name.setText(Name);

        // set dateOfBirth if available
        if (birthContact.getDateOfBirth() != null) {
            DateOfBirth dateOfBirth = birthContact.getDateOfBirth();

            Calendar date = dateOfBirth.getDate();
            Calendar nextBirthday = CalendarUtils.nextBirthday(today, date);
            int days = CalendarUtils.timeSpanInDays(today, nextBirthday);
            int newAge = nextBirthday.get(Calendar.YEAR) - date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
            info.setText(getBirthdayText(days, newAge));

            if (days == 0){

                /*Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BirthdayActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Notification n = new Notification.Builder(getContext())
                        .setContentTitle(birthContact.getContact().getName() +" Tomorrow Birthday")
                        .setContentText("Celebrate and say something ")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ucare_icon_app)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0, n);*/

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiveBirth.class);
                final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),(int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                // create an alarm
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                // set tomorrow at midnight
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                //cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

                // trigger alarm
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);

            } if( days == 1) {

                //Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BirthdayActivity.class);
                //PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Notification n = new Notification.Builder(getContext())
                        .setContentTitle(birthContact.getContact().getName() +" Tomorrow Birthday")
                        .setContentText("We Will Remind You Tomorrow")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ucare_icon_app)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        //.setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0, n);

            }else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiveBirth.class);
                final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.cancel(pIntent);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }


    private String getBirthdayText(int days, int newAge) {
        String text;
        switch (days) {
        case 0:
            text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.summary_today), newAge);
            break;
        case 1:
            text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.summary_tomorrow), newAge);
            break;
        default:
            text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.summary_other), days, newAge);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

BirthContact.java

```
    public class BirthContact {

    private final Contact contact;
    private final DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;


    public BirthContact(Contact contact, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth) {
        super();

        this.contact = contact;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public DateOfBirth getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this.dateOfBirth != null) {
            return String.format("%s (%s)", this.contact.getName(), this.getDateOfBirth().getDate());
        }
        return this.contact.getName();
    }
}
```

MultiListAdapter.java

```
    public class MultiListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<ListAdapter> listAdapters = new ArrayList<ListAdapter>();

    public List<ListAdapter> getListAdapters() {
        return listAdapters;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for (ListAdapter listAdapter : this.listAdapters) {
            count += listAdapter.getCount();
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        int positionOffset = 0;
        for (ListAdapter listAdapter : this.listAdapters) {
            if (position - positionOffset < listAdapter.getCount()) {
                return listAdapter.getItem(position - positionOffset);
            }
            positionOffset += listAdapter.getCount();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int positionOffset = 0;
        for (ListAdapter listAdapter : this.listAdapters) {
            if (position - positionOffset < listAdapter.getCount()) {
                return listAdapter.getView(position - positionOffset, convertView, parent);
            }
            positionOffset += listAdapter.getCount();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        int viewTypeCount = 0;
        for (ListAdapter listAdapter : this.listAdapters) {
            viewTypeCount += listAdapter.getViewTypeCount();
        }
        // viewTypeCount may not be 0
        if (viewTypeCount == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return viewTypeCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int positionOffset = 0;
        int typeOffset = 0;
        for (ListAdapter listAdapter : this.listAdapters) {
            if (position - positionOffset < listAdapter.getCount()) {
                return typeOffset + listAdapter.getItemViewType(position - positionOffset);
            }
            positionOffset += listAdapter.getCount();
            typeOffset += listAdapter.getViewTypeCount();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        int positionOffset = 0;
        for (ListAdapter listAdapter : this.listAdapters) {
            if (position - positionOffset < listAdapter.getCount()) {
                return listAdapter.isEnabled(position - positionOffset);
            }
            positionOffset += listAdapter.getCount();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in ListView with EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816243/search-in-listview-with-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

make some change in adapter class used below code in adapter i put my assumed birthday data when you implement you define your need of data. like 
BirthdayContactAdapter.java put below code inside.

```
 private List<BirthContact> mBirthContactFilter = new ArrayList<>();
private CustomFilter mFilter;

public BirthdayContactAdapter(Context context, List<BirthContact> mContactList) {
    super(context, R.layout.listviewbirthday);
    this.today = CalendarUtils.todaysCalendar();
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.res = context.getResources();
    this.mBirthContactFilter = mContactList;
    mFilter = new CustomFilter();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mBirthContactFilter.size();
}

/**
 * this class for filter data.
 */
class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<BirthContact> filters = new ArrayList<>();
            charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < mBirthContactList.size(); i++) { // actual list to bind
                if (mBirthContactList.get(i).getUserName().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence) || mContactList.get(i).getUserEmail().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)) { // if you bind birthday boy name that.
                    BirthContact contact = new BirthContact();
                    contact.setName(mBirthContactList.get(i).getName()); // hear write your data to add filter define in pojo class.
                    contact.setAge(mBirthContactList.get(i).getAge());
                    filters.add(contact);

                }
            }
            results.count = filters.size();
            results.values = filters;

        } else {
            results.count = mBirthContactList.size();
            results.values = mBirthContactList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        mBirthContactFilter = (ArrayList<BirthContact>) filterResults.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code, but still can not work, there is still an error in "FilterResult"

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way. Add editext before listview.**

```
search_birth.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charText, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                List<BirthContact> arrtL_temp_one = new ArrayList<>();

            chars = chars.toString().toLowerCase();
            if (arrtL_temp_one.size() > 0)
                arrtL_temp_one.clear();
            if (chars.length() == 0) {
                arrtL_temp_one.addAll(birthContacts);
            } else {
                for (int listNo = 0; listNo < birthContacts.size(); listNo++) {
                    if (birthContacts.get(listNo).getFoodName().toLowerCase().contains(chars)) {
                        BirthContact contact = new BirthContact();
                        contact.setName(birthContacts.get(listNo).getName()); // hear write your data to add filter define in pojo class.
                        contact.setAge(birthContacts.get(listNo).getAge());

                        arrtL_temp_one.add(contact);

                    }
                }
            }
                birthdayContactAdapter= new BirthdayContactAdapter(getActivity(), arrtL_temp_one);
                birthday.setAdapter(birthdayContactAdapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: I still confused with "yourmainarraylist"?, I did not find the arraylist in Birthday Adapter

Comment: Send via ? @matinSayyad

Comment: getName(), getAge, setAge(), & setAge still red Text, and getActivity() at birthdayContactAdapter = new BirthdayContactAdapter some red text :(, please helpme

Comment: post your BirthContact class in question

Comment: Oke wait @matinSayyad

Comment: Okay, I will wait

Comment: Try This   contact.setName(birthContacts.get(listNo).getContact().getName());               contact.setAge(birthContacts.get(listNo).getDateOfBirth().getAge());

Comment: oke, but "getActivity()" at birthdayContactAdapter = new BirthdayContactAdapter still red text

Comment: if you are using fragment try getActivity()...if you are using Activity use this or YourActivityName.this

Comment: start teamviewer and give me id

Comment: my teamviewer id 710 273 578

Answer (score 0):

In the ListActivity, on typing a letter addTextChangedListener will be called.

```
 search_birth.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            listAdapter.filter(s); //*just create a method in the adapter ie.public void filter(String s)*
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Create a new arraylist newBirthContact  and addall the originalBirthContact to the newBirthContact

```
private List<BirthContact> newBirthContact = new ArrayList<>();

private List<BirthContact> originalBirthContact= new ArrayList<>();

public BirthdayContactAdapter(Context context, List<BirthContact> originalBirthContact) 
{
      this.originalBirthContact= originalBirthContact;
      this.newBirthContact.addAll(originalBirthContact);

}
```

Create the method filter(String s) in the adapter

```
 public void filter(String s) {

        for (BirthContact mBirthContact : newBirthContact)
            {
              if(mBirthContact.getName()().toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase()))
                {
                    originalBirthContact.add(mBirthContact);
                }
            }

        notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: can not work, there is still an error in "search_birth.addTextChangedListener" -> "listAdapter.filter(s)", in this method change from String to Charsequence (s), an still error.

Comment: get the text directly from the edit_text and pass it to the method filter. ie. listAdapter.filter(search_birth.getText().toString())