# Increase in the fragment list how to do it

Tags: android, list, fragment

I try to increase picture fragment. Increase buttons are no problem.
But today I want to increase the list they compile error.
How can I do it?.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.templistmune, container, false);


            String[] glossary = {"C","B","A","K"
            };
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(templistview.this, R.layout.listview_item, glossary));
//The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>) is undefined for the type templistview
//error The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(templistview, int, String[]) is undefined
            ListView listView = getListView();
//error The method getListView() is undefined for the type templistview
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                        int position, long id) {

                }
            });    


            return view;

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'increase the listview' ? And what does the compile error say?

Comment: Error code I fill in the Remarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend ListActivity

```
MyActivity extends ListActivity
```

Source: ["The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type create"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033791/the-method-setlistadapterarrayadapter-is-undefined-for-the-type-create)

Answer (score 0):

I found Change templistview.this to getActivity()